# Getting a segfault using TTF_RenderText() when the font is loaded using TTF_OpenFontRW()?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

My project is trying to load a font for rendering from a zip file. I use LibZip for accessing the zip, and the procedure I use works fine for all the graphics I'm rendering. However, using the same process for loading a ttf font eventually causes a segfault when I try to render the text using SDL_ttf's TTF_RenderText functions. I've tested that that's the cause by replacing the loading code with TTF_Open and successfully gotten it to load, while loading from zip using my code ends with segfault. Here's the code I use to load the file from the zip:

```
TTF_Font* m_load_font(const char* filename, int fontsize) {
  zip_stat_t filestat;
  uint64_t filetotal;
  SDL_RWops* rwop = SDL_AllocRW();

  //Check to see if the data stream got allocated
  if ( rwop == NULL ) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_SDL, "SDL_AllocRW");
    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    return nullptr;
  }
  //Check to see if the resource zip is open
  if ( cc_zip_res == NULL ) {
    std::cerr << "Font Load Error: Zip File Not Loaded" << std::endl;
    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    return nullptr;
  }
  //Open the file
  zip_file_t* file = zip_fopen(cc_zip_res, filename, 0);
  if (file == NULL) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_ZIP, "zip_fopen");
    zip_fclose(file);
    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    return nullptr;
  }
  //Read the file
  if(zip_stat(cc_zip_res, filename, 0, &filestat) == -1) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_ZIP, "zip_stat");
    zip_fclose(file);
    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    return nullptr;
  }
  //Write data to a data holding array
  char* rwbuffer = new char[filestat.size];
  rwop = SDL_RWFromMem(rwbuffer, filestat.size);
  while(filetotal < filestat.size) {
    char buffer[256];
    int64_t length;
    //read the file into the buffer
    length = zip_fread(file, buffer, 256);
    if (length == -1) {
      u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_ZIP, "zip_fread");
      zip_fclose(file);
      SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
      delete[] rwbuffer;
      return nullptr;
    }
    //write the buffer into the rwop stream
    if ( (size_t)length != SDL_RWwrite(rwop, buffer, 1, (size_t)length) ) {
      u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_SDL, "SDL_RWwrite");
      zip_fclose(file);
      SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
      delete[] rwbuffer;
      return nullptr;
    }
    //Increment the count so that the loop ends
    filetotal += length;
  }
  zip_fclose(file);
  //Return the seek pointer of the RWop to the beginning so that the file can be read
  SDL_RWseek(rwop,0,RW_SEEK_SET);
  //Load the font from the rwop
  TTF_Font* temp = TTF_OpenFontRW(rwop, 0, fontsize);
  SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
  delete[] rwbuffer;
  if (temp == NULL) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_TTF, "TTF_OpenFontRw");
  }
  return temp;
}
```

And here's the code I'm using that has TTF_RenderText:

```
bool CC_Texture::load_from_font(TTF_Font* font, std::string* text, SDL_Color color,
  SDL_Renderer* ren) {
  if (font == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Font is Null in CC_Texture::load_from_font" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  //The wrap length is an estimate, will figure out the exact
  SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(font, text->c_str(), color, 600);
  if (surf == NULL) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_TTF, "TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped");
    return false;
  }
  texture = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>(SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, surf),
    SDL_DestroyTexture);
  if (texture.get() == NULL) {
    u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_SDL, "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

EDIT: I should also say that I used a debugger to dump the contents of rwbuffer after it did the load and it was a valid font file, so it doesn't seem like the zip reading is the problem.

Comment: Not the answer, but you might want to read about *scope guards*. Then you won't need to duplicate resource-freeing code ever again.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think the RWops must stay valid while the font is used.

Comment: That, plus leaking rwops with pointless `AllocRW` and never freeing it.

Comment: @whitehawk It's kinda strange to try to solve your problem by putting up a bounty here. You should rather post a separate question with a [mcve] for your code.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

## TD;DR

### The problem

You freed the `SDL_RWops` and its buffer right after opening them using `TTF_OpenFontRW`, even though such a `TTF_Font` is closely linked to those and freeing them essentially means breaking it, as it'll make the `TTF_Font` try to access memory that you freed, resulting in a segfault error.

### The solution

Remove the `SDL_FreeRW(rwop);`and `delete[] rwbuffer;` line from your `m_load_font`function, and put them wherever you close your font.

To simplify things, you can make the second parameter of `TTF_OpenFontRW` a `1` instead of `0` to have `rwop` automatically closed whenever you close your font, but you will still need to `delete[] rwbuffer;` manually, right after you close your font.

### Note

> I'm keeping my RWops alive and not freeing it.

Make sure you keep BOTH your RWops **AND** the buffer that is linked to it alive. The RWops alone isn't enough, both the RWops and the buffer you have opened it with must NOT be freed for as long as you are using your font.

## The long answer

### How does SDL_RWOps work

#### What the documentation says

According [the documentation for the SDL_RWFromMem function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RWFromMem#remarks) ([mirror link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230731214215/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RWFromMem#remarks)):

> This memory buffer is not copied by the `SDL_RWops`; the pointer you provide must remain valid until you close the stream. Closing the stream will not free the original buffer.

#### What does this mean for us?

What this means is that you can free the buffer linked to your `SDL_RWops` **only** when you are done using said buffer. Otherwise, it'd make your `SDL_RWops` instance invalid, because it will try to read into memory that has been read, resulting in a segmentation fault.

### How does TTF_OpenFontRW work

#### What the documentation implies

For this function, [the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2_ttf/TTF_OpenFontRW) ([mirror link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230731214517/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2_ttf/TTF_OpenFontRW)) says the following:

> If `freesrc` is non-zero, the `SDL_RWops` will be closed before returning, whether this function succeeds or not. SDL_ttf reads everything it needs from the `SDL_RWops` during this call in any case.

We don't really care about the `freesrc` part of the sentence here, what we care about is the other part, which says that in any case (implying no matter the parameters), the TTF_OpenFontRW function will read everything it needs from the `SDL_RWops`, which implies that the `SDL_RWops` is no longer needed after calling this function, right?

It turns out that this statement is **wrong**. See below.

#### `TTF_OpenFontRW`'s actual implementation

At the time of writing, here is how the `TTF_OpenFontRW` function is implemented:

- [`TTF_OpenFontRW` redirect its call to `TTF_OpenFontIndexRW`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L2049-L2052)
- [`TTF_OpenFontIndexRW` redirect its call to `TTF_OpenFontIndexDPIRW`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L2035-L2038)
- [`TTF_OpenFontIndexDPIRW` is implemented](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1757-L1901) as follows.

As can be seen on [line 1800](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1800), the pointer to the SDL_RWops passed to the function is stored in the `TTF_Font` instance that'll be returned to you.

On [line 1812](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1812), we can also see that it is stored in the structure of a stream that is itself stored into the `TTF_Font`instance on [line 1817](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1817).

So:

> SDL_ttf reads everything it needs from the `SDL_RWops` during this call in any case.

This statement is wrong.

But there's more, as we can see at lines [1769 to 1771](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1769-L1771), [1784 to 1786](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1784-L1786) and [1793 to 1795](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1793-L1795), the `SDL_RWops` instance will be closed if the `freesrc` parameter is set to true, but only if there is an error. At no point is it closed if there are no errors!

At [line 1801](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L1801) though, we can see that the `freesrc` boolean is stored into the `TTF_Font` instance, which, as can be see on [line 2754](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/fee14e525f5bd99612b76e2737400d33eddf0595/src/SDL_ttf.c#L2752-L2754), is to close the `SDL_RWops` during the `TTF_Close` call that you will do when you will be done with your font!

So:

> If `freesrc` is non-zero, the `SDL_RWops` will be closed before returning, whether this function succeeds or not.

This statement is wrong, the `SDL_RWops` will be closed only if the function did NOT succeed.

#### What does this mean for us?

The `TTF_Font` instance returned by the `TTF_OpenFontRW` function call is very closely linked to the `SDL_RWops` you passed to it. This instance will require your `SDL_RWops` to remain opened for as long as you keep your font opened.

### Summary of what we know so far

So far, we have figured out that:

- You can't free the buffer you linked to a `SDL_RWops` if you don't close the `SDL_RWops` before doing so. Otherwise, your `SDL_RWops` will become invalid.
- You can't close a `SDL_RWops` you linked to a `TTF_Font` if you don't close the `TTF_Font` before doing so. Otherwise, your `TTF_Font` will become invalid.

### Your error in all of this

Let me write back the content of your `m_load_font` function, simplified:

```
TTF_Font* m_load_font(const char* filename, int fontsize) {
    zip_stat_t filestat;
    uint64_t filetotal;
    SDL_RWops* rwop = SDL_AllocRW();

    /*
    ---
    Code to open the TTF file located in your ZIP
    ---
    */
    
    //Write data to a data holding array
    char* rwbuffer = new char[filestat.size];
    rwop = SDL_RWFromMem(rwbuffer, filestat.size);

    /*
    ---
    Code to write the content of the TTF file you opened into rwbuffer
    ---
    */

    //Load the font from the rwop
    TTF_Font* temp = TTF_OpenFontRW(rwop, 0, fontsize);
    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    delete[] rwbuffer;
    if (temp == NULL) {
        u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_TTF, "TTF_OpenFontRw");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Here, as you can see, right after opening your `TTF_Font` by passing `rwop` to `TTF_OpenFontRW` call, you free `rwop` by calling `SDL_FreeRW`.
Your `TTF_Font` won't be usable if you close its `SDL_RWops`, that needs to be done only after you close your font when you no longer need it.

But that's not all, even if you didn't close the `SDL_RWops`, you delete `rwbuffer`, which is the buffer `rwop` is linked to.
So even without closing the `SDL_RWops`, you delete the buffer that holds its content, rendering it unusable.

### The solution

#### Making your code work

You should remove both the `SDL_RWops` closing line and the and buffer `delete[]` line, as such:

```
TTF_Font* m_load_font(const char* filename, int fontsize) {
    zip_stat_t filestat;
    uint64_t filetotal;
    SDL_RWops* rwop = SDL_AllocRW();

    /*
    ---
    Code to open the TTF file located in your ZIP
    ---
    */
    
    //Write data to a data holding array
    char* rwbuffer = new char[filestat.size];
    rwop = SDL_RWFromMem(rwbuffer, filestat.size);

    /*
    ---
    Code to write the content of the TTF file you opened into rwbuffer
    ---
    */

    //Load the font from the rwop
    TTF_Font* temp = TTF_OpenFontRW(rwop, 0, fontsize);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        u_error(std::cerr, CC_ERROR_TTF, "TTF_OpenFontRw");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

#### Avoiding memory leaks

With the way you organized your code, it will cause a memory leak, as you don't save your `SDL_RWops` anywhere to close it whenever you close your font, and nor do you save `rwbuffer`'s value as a pointer to delete it as soon as you close its corresponding `SDL_RWops`.

Here is a suggestion on how to fix it, though it's up to you to decide what is for best for your needs.

First, I'd change `TTF_OpenFontRW(rwop, 0, fontsize)` into `TTF_OpenFontRW(rwop, 1, fontsize)` in order to tell the font to automatically close the `SDL_RWops` that your `TTF_Font` holds as soon as you call `TTF_Close` to free it.

But closing the `SDL_RWops` won't free the buffer it was linked to.
So, I'd keep track of `rwbuffer`'s value as a pointer, to have `delete[] rwbuffer` placed right after you `TTF_Close` your `TTF_Font`.

### Conclusion

Most of the time when you get a segfault, it means that you either access memory that you didn't allocate, or memory that you freed.

So whenever you get one in a case like yours, try commenting your close, free and delete calls to see if it fixes it.

Don't leave them commented for eternity though, it could cause memory leaks! If one of those calls is responsible for your segfault, then try to figure out why (or ask on Stack Overflow if you can't figure out why, of course) and put that call that was responsible for the segfault somewhere else, where is actually belongs to.

If you use arrays, then check for indices to see if you aren't reading further than your array's size, as that can cause segfaults as well.